# Image on Material UI CardMedia

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I´m having some troubles on getting an image from props on a CardMedia image:

```
<Card className={classes.card}>
    <CardMedia 
        className={classes.img}
        image={this.props.recipe.thumbnail}
    />
    <CardContent className={classes.content}>
        <Typography gutterBottom variant="headline" component="h2">
            {this.props.recipe.title}
        </Typography>
        <Typography component="p">
            {this.props.recipe.ingredients}
        </Typography>
    </CardContent>
    <CardActions>
        <Button 
            href={this.props.recipe.href}
            Recipe
        </Button> 
    </CardActions>
</Card>
```

It just doesnt render at all the images; all the other props values are rendered as they has to.
Also as Material UI I had specified the CardMedia height on a JS css.

Does anyone knows why this happens?

Comment: Maybe some `recipe` doesn't have `thumbnail`?

Comment: Yes it does...I had already made an <img> element inside the card media with the same src and it worked. But it should work without the img element; it should work just by referencing on the CardMedia element

Comment: @Marcelo Did you find a solution for this ? Same error here . Please post if you found one. Thanks !

Comment: how can I get a network image working (using https)?

Comment: basically my props refer to a URL

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I had the Same Issue. Finally Got it Working doing this:

```
const styles = {
    media: {
      height: 0,
      paddingTop: '56.25%', // 16:9,
      marginTop:'30'
    }
};

     
<CardMedia
  className={classes.media}
  image={require('assets/img/bg2.jpg')} // require image
  title="Contemplative Reptile"
  style={styles.media} // specify styles
/>
```

You can also check :
https://codesandbox.io/s/9zqr09zqjo - No option to load images . The image location is my local

[image]

Comment: Nice solution...just wanted to add that if you attach a codesanbox, please be sure that it is working. Currently attached codesandbox is crashing everywhere; I´ve managed to get it working...If you could update it it would be great

Comment: linked sandbox does not compile

Comment: To make it work I need it to add '.default' , eg:  image={require('assets/img/bg2.jpg').default}

Comment: I've been struggling with the size for hours, it doesn't look the way I want it but pretty close, thanks m8!!

Answer (score 15):

I have read the docs and also notice that you have to specify the height to display images. While they say you should create a component with style I feel that a simpler way of doing it is by using the style prop directly:

```
<CardMedia
  style={{height: 0, paddingTop: '56.25%'}}
  image={project.image}
  title="lorem ipsum"
/>
```

The other options would be to create a style object first and then render the component withStyle as the docs said:

```
const styles = {
  card: {
    maxWidth: 345,
  },
  media: {
    height: 0,
    paddingTop: '56.25%', // 16:9
  },
};

function SimpleMediaCard(props) {
  const { classes } = props;
  return (
    <div>
      <Card className={classes.card}>
        <CardMedia
          className={classes.media}
          image="/static/images/cards/contemplative-reptile.jpg"
          title="Contemplative Reptile"
        />
      </Card>
    </div>
  );
}

export default withStyles(styles)(SimpleMediaCard);
```

Answer (score 10):

to set fallback image on CardMedia, you can try this:

```
import FALLBACK_IMAGE from 'src/assets/images/fallback_image.png';

const onMediaFallback = event => event.target.src = FALLBACK_IMAGE;
<CardMedia
 component="img"
 className={classes.media}
 image="/static/images/cards/contemplative-reptile.jpg"
 title="Contemplative Reptile"
 onError={onMediaFallback}
/>
```

Comment: Not sure why this got voted down, this answer solved my problem: `component="img" is what I am missing,

Answer (score 6):

I was facing the same issue.
A good workaround would be to use the 'img' element along with the 'src' attribute inside the CardMedia body instead of passing it as an attribute to the CardMedia.

```
<CardMedia>
 <img src={this.props.recipe.thumbnail} alt="recipe thumbnail"/>
</CardMedia>
```

And while passing the props to the class I sent the image path as an object. In your case, suppose recipe is an object with thumbnail as one of the attributes. Then in the parent class, I would write the prop as:

```
...
recipe = {
  .
  .
  thumbnail: require('assets/images/img1.jpg'),
  //make sure the path of the image is relative to parent class where you are defining the prop 
  .
  .
}
...
```

Here I am sending the path of the image as an object. This worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

After updating from 4.9 => 4.12

**add `component="img"` prop**

(it had `0` height in DOM after the update despite setting it to `200px`)

`<CardMedia className={classes.pageMedia} component='img' image='/static/img.jpg' />`

Answer (score 0):

In my case it worked after changing the value of height other than 0 in the style

Not Worked:

```
const styles = {
  card: {
    maxWidth: 345,
  },
  media: {
    height: 0,
    paddingTop: '56.25%', // 16:9
  },
};
```

Worked:

```
const styles = {
  card: {
    maxWidth: 345,
  },
  media: {
    height: "300px" or "10em",
    paddingTop: '56.25%', // 16:9
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `src` property instead of `img` property