# MaterialUI card view not showing

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-design-lite

I am adding a card view in my webpage. But the contents in the card gets loaded in the normal view instead of card view.
Here's the Sample code i tried:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import MuiThemeProvider from "@material-ui/core/styles/MuiThemeProvider";
import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";
import Toolbar from "@material-ui/core/Toolbar";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import MenuIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Menu";
import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card";

import CardActions from "@material-ui/core/CardActions";
import CardContent from "@material-ui/core/CardContent";
import CardMedia from "@material-ui/core/CardMedia";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import CardActionArea from "@material-ui/core/CardActionArea";

class HomePage extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
          <AppBar style={{ background: "#0080ff" }} position="static">
            <Toolbar>
              <Typography
                color="inherit"
                variant="h4"
                className={{ flexGrow: 1 }}
              >
                My Page
              </Typography>
              <Button color="inherit">Home</Button>
            </Toolbar>
          </AppBar>
        </div>
        <div>
          <Card className={{ maxWidth: 345 }}>
            <CardActionArea>
              <CardMedia
                className={{ height: 140 }}
                image="https://images.pexels.com/photos/170811/pexels-photo-170811.jpeg"
                title="My App"
              />
              <CardContent>
                <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
                  Welcome to My APP
                </Typography>
              </CardContent>
            </CardActionArea>
            <CardActions>
              <Button size="small" color="primary">
                Go to Login Page
              </Button>
            </CardActions>
          </Card>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default HomePage;
```

The contents get loaded but without the card view. I checked material ui website [card in material ui website](https://material-ui.com/components/cards/) But I don't know where I am doing wrong. Help me with some solutions

This is the output page i got without card view:

[image]

Comment: Found the Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50272814/image-on-material-ui-cardmedia

Answer (score 0):

try adding in card media the following prop.

> component="img"

Add styles individually like making a styles objects.Not adding styles in classname.

What data is not loading in the card view? Please can you be elaborate!

Comment: I have added the output page in my question. The data showing without card view

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. It is resolved by wrapping the HomePage component within a Container

```
 <Container>  
 <HomePage />
 </Container>
```