# Unable to Display Image from S3 Using Signed URL : React/Amplify

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, asynchronous, amazon-s3

I am attempting to retrieve and display images from S3 using a signed URL. I can log the Signed URL to the console, click it, and it will download the image locally. The downloaded image is not corrupted in any way.

: Component Hierarchy

```
App
- Maps
-- Map
```

The *App* component manages filtering of maps, the filtered maps state is then passed to the *Maps* component which dynamically renders *Map* components.

```
export default function Maps({ maps }) {
    return (
        <Carousel
            autoPlay={false}
            PrevIcon={<ArrowCircleLeftIcon fontSize='large' />}
            NextIcon={<ArrowCircleRightIcon fontSize='large' />}
        >
            {maps.map((map, i) => (
                <Map key={i} map={map} />
            ))}
        </Carousel>
    )
}
```

My *Map* component holds state containing the Maps Image URL, and a *useEffect* hook which calls a *getImg* function.

```
export default function Map({ map }) {
    const [mapImg, setMapImg] = useState(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        if (map.uri) {
            getImg(map.uri).then((res) => {
                console.log(res)
                setMapImg(res)
            })
        }
    }, [map.uri])

return (
    <CardMedia
        component='img'
        alt='random nature'
        height='550'
        image={mapImg}
    />
)
```

Finally, the *getImg* function.

```
export const getImg = (uri) => {
    const uriToS3Path = (uri) => {
        let path = uri.substring(0, 6)
        const file = uri.substring(6) + '.TIF'
        path = path.split('').join('/') + '/'
        return path + file
    }

    const filePath = uriToS3Path(uri)
    return Storage.get(filePath, { contentType: 'image/tiff' })
}
```

Don't be confused by *map.uri*, basically this property determines the key for the S3 object, hence the *uriToS3Path* function as above. I don't receive any debug errors, I can retrieve the link but the image does not display. Is it due to some asynchronous activity or should the entire approach to fetching be altered?

Many Thanks.

Update:
Inspecting the *Application* tab within the developer console. You can see that the S3 Image is listed (92.TIF), but the preview is broken.

[image: Application Tab - Developer Console]

Comment: Your `getImg` function isn't declared async.

Comment: @jarmod It initially was. It does not affect the retrieval of images. I am using "then()" to handle the call of the getImg function. I receive a Signed URL perfectly fine, just the application does not display the resulting image using the Signed URL...

Comment: If you debug the CardMedia component in devtools, is `image={mapImg}` actually correctly set to the pre-signed URL?

Comment: @jarmod Yes, the image property is set to the correct URL. I downloaded the image locally using the same link without issues.

Comment: Related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50272814/image-on-material-ui-cardmedia), in case you haven't see it.

Comment: @jarmod No luck with that article. Thanks though. I did try a simplified component not using MUI elements, still nothing showing. Looking since, as I mentioned I can download the image using the URL no issues, but going to the "Application" tab in the developer console and inspecting the "Frames" section, the image is sitting there (E.G. 92.TIF) but clicking on it gives no preview of the image like it does for others...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243716/discussion-between-alanphil-and-jarmod).